# Authorize dot net response id String value not saving in proper formats MySQL

Tags: php, wordpress, authorize.net

Hope you are doing well ... 
I have got a stuck 
I have a JSON response from the gateway authorize.net

```
{"success":true,"message":"Transaction successful.","transaction_id":"40009536456","customer_profile_id":"1503196969","payment_profile_id":["1502547789"],"transaction_response_code":"1","auth_code":"XPHPOL","message_code":"1"}
```

And I am adding this on User meta, But in the database, it's real values not showing, in the place of value only showing 'c'.

See screenshot :

[image]

But it should be like this :

[image]

Anyone can help what happening there?

In the code, I tried the following, also tried without trim() the :

```
 add_user_meta( $user_id, 'transaction_id', trim($payment_data['transaction_id']) );
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'customer_profile_id', trim($payment_data['customer_profile_id']) );
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'payment_profile_id', trim($payment_data['payment_profile_id'] ));
```

Comment: How is `$payment_data` being populated? What does `var_dump($payment_data);` show?

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks, get resolved there was invalid data type on $payment_data .